# Pre-populating a High Replication Datastore for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have the following problem

- I have around 25,000 XML files I need to pre populate the data store with
- I am using a High Replication Datastore therefore I can't use the bulk uploader for that

I can't of course upload those files as part of my WEB-INF because the limit is 3000 files.

One solution I can think of is to write a client that send one file at a time to my Web App then I parse it and insert it into the Data Store but 
that will eat up my entire Band Width and time consuming.

Is there another solution for my problem?

Comment: Does this data really need to be in the datastore? If it's mostly static, could you simply upload it in a zip and access it from your app?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the mapper library to process lines from an uploaded file?  You could then preprocess your xml files to csv files and then upload them, have a handler that creates an entity for each line.

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce